# Cannot open pdf aws lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, postman, pdflib

I'm facing an issue with my lambda function. When I run it in Postman, the PDF isn't displayed. I've also tried the 'Send and Download' option, but it says the file doesn't have a valid format. Any suggestions?

I have an issue with this lambda function:

```js
const { PDFDocument } = require('pdf-lib');

exports.getAll = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        
        const htmlContent = '<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>';

        const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.create();

        const page = pdfDoc.addPage();

        const { width, height } = page.getSize();
        await page.drawText(htmlContent, { x: 50, y: height - 100 });

        const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=hello_world.pdf');
        res.status(200).send(pdfBytes);
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
};
```

When running it in Postman, the PDF is not displayed. I also tried the 'Send and Download' option, but it shows that the file does not have a valid format. Any suggestions?

My package.json :

```json
{
  "name": "formularios-pdf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "author",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-serverless-express": "^3.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "chrome-aws-lambda": "^10.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.17.1"
  }
}
```

Post man:

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Can you try saving the response to disk and open it with a pdf viewer

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not an images.

Answer (score 1):

Few things are you are doing it incorrect:

1. The function params has `(event, context, callback)` and not `(req, res)`.
2. API response should have base64 data. For that you can use `saveAsBase64`.
3. In case you have API Gateway connected to it. Then you will have to enable Binary media types.
4. Also note that `drawText` method takes normal string and not HTML string. Although it will work but it will render entire HTML string.

Demo example:

```
const { PDFDocument } = require("pdf-lib");

export async function hello(event, context) {
  try {
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.create();
    const text = "Hello World!";
    const page = pdfDoc.addPage([350, 400]);
    page.moveTo(110, 200);
    page.drawText(text);
    const pdfBase64 = await pdfDoc.saveAsBase64();
    const filename = "example.pdf";

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
        "Content-Disposition": `inline; filename=${filename}`,
      },
      body: pdfBase64,
      isBase64Encoded: true,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating PDF:", error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ error: "Internal Server Error" }),
    };
  }
}
```

**Enable Binary media types**

1. Goto your API dashboard
2. From the left panel, goto **API Settings**
3. Under Binary media types, Select `Manage Media Types`
4. Add "*/*" to enable all binary support. You can restrict it based on your requirements.
5. Goto Resources from the left panel and **Deploy API** from the top right side.

NOTE: It might take some time to reflect the changes of step 5. Took 5 minutes for me.

In case you are using Function URL, then just function deployment in enough.